# Scale drawings in Illustrator, maintain proportions of line weights and effects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

My problem is that when I scale down my drawing, the line weights stay the same, blotting out the artwork. If I scale up, the line weights become too thin. I've noticed that parametric effects don't scale together with the drawing.

How do I scale drawings in Adobe Illustrator and still maintain the proportions of line weights, gradients, and effects such as offset path?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In the `Preferences > General` area, make sure `Scale Strokes & Effects` is selected.

Comment: Why the heck isn't this checked by default? >__<

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to  select the object and go to `Object > Path > Outline Stroke`. Of course this is only for paths. And btw I would go with lawndartcatcher on this one, my proposal is just another option to have in mind.

Answer (score -1):

After you have finished the drawing, select it and go to "object -> expand. This will mantein the same proportions you have when you scale it.

Comment: Actually, it won't. If your line weights aren't scaling the lines won't scale - if you started with 1 px wide lines and you scale your drawing to 200% you'll still have lines that are 1 px wide (in other words, your lines will now be half the weight but twice the size).

Answer (score -3):

On a PC go to `Edit > Preferences > General` and check `Scale & Stroke Effects`

Comment: And the result is? What will I see? Please explain more ...

Comment: What does this add to lawndartcatcher's accepted answer? Please do not duplicate answers. Thank you!