# Scaling strokes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scale drawings in Illustrator, maintain proportions of line weights and effects](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2455/scale-drawings-in-illustrator-maintain-proportions-of-line-weights-and-effects)

When you minimize large vectors that contain outlines & text to a small vector the stroke & size does adapt to the new size.

Is there a way to overcome this, or fix the final result? Also when I make the vector smaller and try to manually fix stroke I am giving 1 pt, is it optimal to go under 1 pt.?

[image: Result]

Original
[image: original]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little confused....

Title mentions Photoshop, but you tagged it with Illustrator. I edited the title since your screen shots are clearly Illustrator.

In Illustrator, check the Preferences. **Preferences  > General > Scale Strokes & Effect**. If that option is not checked, then strokes and effect retain their original size when you scale objects.

*Oh, to answer the stroke size question.*... yes you can go below 1pt. I would never go below 0.25pt however. Anything below 0.25pt runs the risk of being dropped when printed.

Comment: Thanks for adding the images, yea I meant illustrator but for some reason I had Photoshop in the title, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

**Object > Expand** seems to do the trick as well.